# RDS - Export Data from MYSQL Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I made a big technical mistake when I launched my mysql database by selecting the largest storage setting by my database. As a result I deleted the instance, but I do have a snapshot of the last instance. I don't want to reinstate the snapshot and get charged, so I was wondering if there was a way for me to export the data from my last snapshot into a csv file and then create a new instance with smaller storage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you can do with an RDS snapshot is restore it into a fresh RDS instance. Once you have the instance, you can export the data as CSV or using mysqldump.

From that, you can terminate the temporary instance and create your new, smaller instance and import the data.

But you cannot get at the data directly with the snapshot.